# PowerBI: Group by key, retrieve last nonblank value off another row with filters

Tags: powerbi, data-integrity

I'm trying to plug the holes on the dataset that I currently have.
My N_order is the key for grouping. As you can see in below example, I've null values for the column ship_meth, when the status is 'fulfilled'.

I'd love to create a new desired_column that can retrieve the value from any of the other statuses for that N_order (for example, 'new_order') and paste it on the row with the 'fulfilled' status.

I'm not able to provide a solid example of what I've been trying, as is not working anywhere near what I'd like. Just going to point out that it doesnt work with filldown/up function as i've different statuses on the orders, and different ship_meth.

| N_order | ship_meth | status | desired_column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50010000116187 | ENKM | picked | ENKM |
| 50010000116187 | ENKM | accepted | ENKM |
| 50010000116187 | null | fulfilled | ENKM |
| 50010000116325 | null | fulfilled | ENRC |
| 50010000116325 | ENRC | accepted | ENRC |
| 50010000116325 | ENRC | rejected | ENRC |

Appreciate your time and effort.

Suk

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

You could try:

```
desired = CALCULATE(LASTNONBLANK(Tabelle1[ship_meth], Tabelle1[ship_meth]), FILTER(all(Tabelle1), [N_order] = EARLIER(Tabelle1[N_order])))
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Hi Marco, good day,

Kindly note that this isn't working properly. In the example you posted, it's bringing a different value for the N_order: 50010000116187 on the desired column.

This is also happening on my dataset, and it's bringing a completly different desired value from another N_order.

Appreciate your suggestion, and if you could help me out tinker it out.

Best regards,

Comment: Sorry that I haven't noticed that!! I've updated my answer. Now it should work. Could you test and give a short feedback?